# Python Read text and numbers from FORM screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, python-multiprocessing, tesseract

I am experimenting with python to read words and numbers from screenshots of FORM, something like a scoreboard that can change several times a second. I think the project can be divided into 2 big parts:

1. Take screenshot of the forms several times a second

> I already have some hint to use win32API for faster screenshot here.

2. Read the words and numbers from the screenshot with reference of blank form

> For this, I already have general idea from the youtube video below
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUOcY9ZpKxw
> what I understood is, to apply tesseract to very specific point/ area in the form.
> But with this method in the second part, I have a hunch that the execution time is rather slow.
> (based from what I see from the video)

So my question is, is there any fast way to read a scoreboard that changes several times a second?

Edit:

Below is my current best effort with the project. I only submit the second part, which is the current bottleneck here.
The image can be found here.

[image]

The problem here is, even for just one frame of screenshot, tesseract need around 3 seconds to finish. I tried to use multiprocessing, but it seems my code is not clean enough, so the result is worse than not using it.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import time
import concurrent.futures
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd ="C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

"the height of each field"
h=19

"the list of each field's area and name"
fields=[[(75,5),(130,h),"line 1"],
     [(75,5+h),(130,2*h),"line 2"],
     [(75,5+2*h),(130,3*h),"line 3"],
     [(75,5+3*h),(130,4*h),"line 4"],
     [(75,5+4*h),(130,5*h),"line 5"],
     [(75,5+5*h),(130,6*h),"line 6"],
     [(75,5+6*h),(130,7*h),"line 7"],
     [(75,5+7*h),(130,8*h),"line 8"],
     [(75,5+8*h),(130,9*h),"line 9"],
     [(75,5+9*h),(130,10*h),"line 10"]]

a = time.time()

"loading filled forms"
img = cv2.imread("filled.jpg") 

myData = []

"function to crop and OCR the image"
def read(field):
    imgCrop = img[field[0][1]:field[1][1],field[0][0]:field[1][0]]
    data=pytesseract.image_to_string(imgCrop)
    return data

"use this for serial processing"
for field in fields:
    myData.append(read(field)) 
    
"use this for multi processing"
#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
 #       results = executor.map(read, fields) 
    
    #for result in results:
     #   myData.append(result)

print (myData)
b = time.time()
print(b-a)
```

EDIT 2:

It seems tesseract by default, using multiprocessing and using multiprocessing manually will only hinder the processing speed.
Also, it seems that OCR and image recognition, particularly on its speed and accuracy are still in active research right now. So, maybe I need to wait a little bit more.
Last, I will try to use Google Cloud Vision in the future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you aren't asking how to grab the screen quickly... right? because there are libraries for that, and they can do it more than a few times per second. one library is `mss` (find it on PyPI, i.e. install with pip)

Comment: no. my problem is with the second part, how to extract data quickly with tesseract. for the first, i already heard about mss, but i decided to use win32API function directly to give head start for data processing. according to my research, it can record up to 30-40 frames per second.

Comment: sorry i can not upload any code now because that would be too long and i need to prepare it. i just need general directions / ideas / websites if any, so i can proceed on my own.